# How to run tests on the command line

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, instruments

How do I run tests on the command line; for example:

```
instruments -w a2de620d4fc33e91f1f2f8a8cb0841d2xxxxxxxx -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate TestAutomation -e UIASCRIPT /Users/jc/Documents/Dev/TestAutomation/TestAutomation/TestUI/Test-2.js
```

But this command cannot run, and outputs `Instruments Usage Error : Specified target process is invalid`.

What is the correct usage with Xcode6.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem,here is the correct command,:

```
 instruments -w 69032487ed2e6c53fc186cdec058327028b7f9fd -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate mixtest -e UIASCRIPT ~/desktop/test.js
```